# How do I remove a package which is published on CRAN?

Tags: r, cran

I have published a package on CRAN. I would like to remove it from CRAN now. Is this possible? If it's possible then Please provide a step by step procedure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about the policies and procedures of the Comprehensive R Archive Network and has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 7):

> Packages will not normally be removed from CRAN: however, they may be
>   archived, including at the maintainer’s request.

Source: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html